# how to share the token between classes

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api, stateless

I have having a design issue with asp.net web-api and would like to know how to solve this problem

```
public abstract class BaseApiController<TEntity> : ApiController where TEntity : Entity
{

    protected string GetUsername()
    {
        return Utilities.GetUsername(Request.Headers.Authorization);
    }

     //some other code

 }

public class StakeholderApiController : BaseApiController<Stakeholders>
{
      ILogger _logger = new CustomApiLogger("StkhManager", GetUsername())

     //some other code

}
```

now the problem I have is:

I have the BaseApiController which I am using the share certain functionality between all ApiControllers.

And then I have some specified ApiController for certain not shared functionality.

Now while doing logging, I do want to log the logged in user's name, the problem is I have to pass it everytime I create a new instance, is there a way I can make the logged in user's name global for the current api request so that it can be accessed everywhere.

I cannot make it static, otherwise for others request it will give wrong username.

is there a way I can avoid passing it everytime. Given that webapi is stateless, so session cant be used, is there anyother way??

I am using angularjs front end, hence I am NOT using any authorization technique provided by MVC/.net

Note:

1. I cannot move creation of Logger to base class for certain reasons
2. This is just one example, I want to use the logged in user's name in many other place. Hence dont want to pass it around.

Comment: Have you tried using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`?

Comment: I am using angularjs on client side, hence setting nothing releated to CurrentPrincipal as of now. But if you could share code on how could I set it, it would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard pattern in setting and accessing principal with ASP.NET Web API. From an `ApiController` such as your `BaseApiController`, you can just use the `User` property to retrieve the same. To set it, typically, the `HttpRequestContext` is obtained from the request object and the principal is set like so.

`Request.GetRequestContext().Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(...);`

BTW, you can access the current request object in the Web API pipeline pretty much from anywhere.

Comment: but where should i initialized Principal, in BaseApiController?? or on login??

Comment: You should set the principal after authentication.